# Pagination using Criteria APIs with filter/restriction on child object in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, pagination, hibernate-criteria

I not able to get expected pagination result. I am getting multiple entries of the same parent object for each its child entry as pagination output. However, requirement is to have a single entry for each parent object with all its children attached.
I have tried using `criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)`.
However, it returns single parent entry with only one child`entry attached.

Thanks in advance! :)

Object Mappings :

> Product --OneToOne-- Owner
>
> Owner --OneToMany-- Users (ElementCollection)
>
> Owner --OneToMany-- Groups (ElementCollection)

Code Snippet :

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Product.class);
criteria.createCriteria("owner", "o").createAlias("o.users", "u", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("o.groups", "g", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
Criterion userCriterion = Restrictions.eq("u.elements", <USER_NAME>);
Criterion groupCriterion = Restrictions.in("g.elements", <GROUP_LIST>);
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(userCriterion, groupCriterion));
criteria.setFirstResult(<page> * <numberPerPage>);
criteria.setMaxResults(<numberPerPage>);
return (List<Product>) criteria.list();
```

Comment: We'd like to see your criteria then we can provide some feed back.

Comment: @WilderValera I have added code scnippet. Please check if it helps.